# Is there any WebBased compiled to embed in my WebApp

Tags: flask, web-applications

I have developed a webapp where one can practice sql.
I want to provide a editor like TryIt where I can store Tables and user can write query in editor and get the result.

I am searching for a solution,but not found anything that suits my need.
Repl.it compiler can be embeded ,but problem with that is,we cannot store tables.,and if a user delete it,the code is deleted for every user who is using it.

Is there anything like tryit editor or like one which is here -> https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/joins-hr/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down a bit until you reach the embedded Python interpreter.
Type in the Python code you would like to embed on your website.
Click the menu item `</>` Embed .
Copy and paste the code `<iframe> ... </iframe>` into your website.